# Javascript create img with only one dimension set causes stretching in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

If I use the code below to set an images width but not height, instead of scaling the height proportionally like Safari and FF, IE is just displaying the images actual height causing it to stretch (my width setting is to display the image at a smaller than original size).

```
nImg = document.createElement('img');
nImg.setAttribute("src",'img.jpg');
nImg.setAttribute("width","100");
c.appendChild(nImg);
```

Comment: I seem to have got round it by using the max-width property in CSS and assigning the image the relevant class in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You should not specify an empty height. If you want just to set the width, than add the width but not the height. If you want to keep the same size constraint, you will need to set the height also but not with an empty string.

If you omit the height, the default behaviour is not the keep the constraint. W3C said :

> Always specify both the height and width attributes for images. If
>   height and width are set, the space required for the image is reserved
>   when the page is loaded. However, without these attributes, the
>   browser does not know the size of the image, and cannot reserve the
>   appropriate space to it. The effect will be that the page layout will
>   change during loading (while the images load).

Comment: Sorry that line wasn't supposed to be there I just tried it out like that, they same thing happens without it.

Comment: While that may be true in the spec this does work fine in IE when the image is loaded in regular HTML and not generated by Javascript.